# How to show progress bar in one activity and fetch soap response in another activity

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to android. I'm using web service to fetch data to show in app.I'm getting while showing progress bar. I read similar posts here which says that updating data is not possible in do in background method but I still get the same error.

Main problem is that I have button in one activity (screen which have only buttons and clicking on each button,a unique web service is called) and on clicking that button it is moving to another activity where a web service response is rendered.

This is my code:

```java
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);
       new SoapAccessTask().execute(null,null,null);
    }
    private class SoapAccessTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd = null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPreExecute();
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(DummyActivity.this,"","Loading...");
            pd.setCancelable(true);


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxxx/";

            final String METHOD_NAME = "getStockReportDetails";
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            final String URL = "xxxxxx?wsdl";
            String fp_shop;
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapPackage = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(12);
            HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            Vector<SoapObject> rs = null;
            try {


                fp_shop = "12345";

                PropertyInfo pack = new PropertyInfo();
                pack.setName("shop_no");
                pack.setValue(fp_shop);

                request.addProperty(pack);
                soapPackage.setOutputSoapObject(request);


                http.call(NAMESPACE, soapPackage); 
                //SoapObject req = (SoapObject) soapPackage.bodyOut;
                pd.setMessage("Fetching Details from the Server....");
                System.out.println("request contents : " + request.toString());
                rs = (Vector<SoapObject>) soapPackage.getResponse();
                System.out.println("response from the server : " + rs);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot access the web service" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
`
```

I'm getting this error and I've tried all sorts like changing return types and relocating methods within the body.

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

or

> Activity com.epolicing.DummyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40555c68 that was originally added here
>   01-20 19:36:53.685: E/WindowManager(1191): android.view.WindowLeaked: DummyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40555c68 that was originally added here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Main problem is that i have button in one activity(screen which have
>   only buttons and clicking on each button,a unique web service is
>   called) and on clicking that button it is moving to another activity
>   where a web service response is rendered.

Put code for start another activity in `onPostExecute()` of your AsyncTask after dismissing the Progress Dialog.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pd.dismiss();

   // Your code for start second activity goes here

}
```

And also remove `Toast` from **catch block** in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Thanks for ur response!!!!!!do u want me to put web service fetching code in postexecute?If so,what should i put in doinbackground method?Morover,First activity is only for showing buttons,i cant add code there bcos it messes up.Please tell me clearly with example.,,,,